# why does this give me the wrong customerNumber?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to get the customer that pay the maximum amount.  It gave me the maximum amount but the wrong customer. what should i do?

```
SELECT temp.customerNumber, MAX( temp.max ) AS sum
FROM (
    SELECT p.customerNumber, p.amount AS max
    FROM payments p
    GROUP BY p.customerNumber
) AS temp
```

Comment: Do you want to know what to do, or do you want us to explain what went wrong?

Comment: why do you label something as max to then MAX() it in the outer query and label it sum? do you want the MAX() on the inner query and then SUM(temp.max) AS sum in the outer query?

Comment: the opossite! John Ruddell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a join, possibly as follows:-

```
SELECT *
FROM payments
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(amount) AS MaxAmount
    FROM payments
) Sub1
ON payments.amount = Sub1.MaxAmount
```

Down side of this is that if 2 people both have the same high payment then both will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the Subquery here:

```
SELECT p.customerNumber, MAX(p.amount) AS max
FROM payments p
GROUP BY p.customerNumber
ORDER BY max DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this is wrong! i need to find and take out this customer to the rest of the query! how do i do that?

Comment: You mean use this `customerNumber` in a `WHERE` clause?  I guess in that case you *would* need a subquery.  `WHERE table.field = (SELECT p.customerNumber FROM payments p GROUP BY p.customerNumber ORDER BY MAX(p.amount) DESC LIMIT 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider that your subselect will return something like

```
customerNumber amount
1              100
2              200
```

Then the outer query will pull up those customer numbers and the MAX of **ALL** the rows, which breaks the link between customer numbers and their respective amounts. You're forcing the LARGES amount from ALL of the groups to be applied to all of the groups:

```
cN   amount
1    200
2    200
```