# how to get the correct 'customerNumber'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to take out now the correct customerNumber but it gaves me the first customer number that it found.

```
SELECT temp.customerNumber, MAX( temp.sum ) AS max
FROM (
    SELECT p.customerNumber, SUM( p.amount ) AS sum
    FROM payments p
    GROUP BY p.customerNumber
) AS temp
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305347/why-does-this-give-me-the-wrong-customernumber

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.  Update your existing question if there are new details you wish to add.

Comment: Don't ask same question again.

Comment: o.k. sorry i just forgot to mention one thing because what i asked at first was wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT temp.customerNumber, MAX( temp.tsum ) AS tmax 
FROM (
    SELECT p.customerNumber, SUM( p.amount ) AS tsum 
    FROM payments p 
    GROUP BY p.customerNumber ) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.customerNumber
```

Try that.

Comment: thats wright! but now i need to take out the customer who has tje maximum and im not get it!

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 temp.customerNumber, temp.tsum AS tmax 
FROM (
    SELECT p.customerNumber, SUM( p.amount ) AS tsum 
    FROM payments p 
    GROUP BY p.customerNumber ) AS temp
ORDER BY tsum DESC